# How to use the BigQuery API using a Python script calling a UDF

Tags: python, google-bigquery, udf

Against a BigQuery table, I'm trying to run a SQL statement calling a UDF. This statement is executed within a Python script and the call is made via the BigQuery API.

When I execute a simple SQL statement without a UDF, it works fine. However, I keep getting the same error when I try to use a UDF script (stored either locally or in a GCS bucket).
This what I get on my local Terminal (I run the script via Python Launcher):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
>   line 840, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[projectId]/queries?alt=json
>   returned "Required parameter is missing">

And this is my Python script:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
key,
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

aservice = build('bigquery','v2',credentials=credentials)
query_requestb = aservice.jobs()

query_data = {
    'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'userDefinedFunctionResources': [
                {
                   'resourceUri': 'gs://[bucketName]/[fileName].js'
                }
            ],
            'query': sql
        }
    },
    'timeoutMs': 100000
}

query_response = query_requestb.query(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,body=query_data).execute(num_retries=0)
```

Any idea what 'parameter is missing' or how I can get this to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying `userDefinedFunctionResources`, use `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION` in the body of your `'query'` with the library referenced as part of the `OPTIONS` clause. You will need to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for this, and you can also refer to the documentation on [user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions). Your query would look something like this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MyJsFunction(x FLOAT64) RETURNS FLOAT64 LANGUAGE js AS """
  return my_js_function(x);
"""
OPTIONS (library='gs://[bucketName]/[fileName].js');

SELECT MyJsFunction(x)
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Elliott. Got it to work using `standard SQL` and calling my functions in two separate UDF files via the `OPTIONS` clause. Note that I had to lower case my `if` in my IF statements in the JS functions as it's *case sensitive* (contrary to if you use a UDF with `legacy SQL`). This solution works. However still keen to understand how we can use it with `legacy SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

The query I wanted to run was to categorise traffic and sales by marketing channel which I usually use a UDF for. This is the query I ran using `standard SQL`. This query is stored in a file which I read and store in the variable `sql`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  mktchannels(source STRING,
    medium STRING,
    campaign STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
return channelGrouping(source,medium,campaign) // where channelGrouping is the function in my channelgrouping.js file which contains the attribution rules
  """ OPTIONS ( library=["gs://[bucket]/[path]/regex.js",
    "gs://[bucket]/[path]/channelgrouping.js"] );
WITH
  traffic AS ( // select fields from the BigQuery table
  SELECT
    device.deviceCategory AS device,
    trafficSource.source AS source,
    trafficSource.medium AS medium,
    trafficSource.campaign AS campaign,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
    SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1e6 as revenue,
    SUM(totals.transactions) as transactions
  FROM
    `[datasetId].[table]`
  GROUP BY
    device,
    source,
    medium,
    campaign)
SELECT
  mktchannels(source,
    medium,
    campaign) AS channel, // call the temp function set above
  device,
  SUM(sessions) AS sessions,
  SUM(transactions) as transactions,
  ROUND(SUM(revenue),2) as revenue
FROM
  traffic
GROUP BY
  device,
  channel
ORDER BY
  channel,
  device;
```

And then in the Python script:

```
fd = file('myquery.sql', 'r')
sql = fd.read()
fd.close()

query_data = {
    'query': sql,
    'maximumBillingTier': 10,
    'useLegacySql': False,
    'timeoutMs': 300000
}
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future!